# criteria Active data provider in Yii 2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I'm trying to display database for each user in descending date order using data provider this works for Yii 1 at controller :

```
         $DataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('ModelName', array(
                'criteria' => array(
                'condition' => 'user_id=' . Yii::app()->user->id,
                'order' => 'submitted_dt DESC',
            ),
            'pagination' => array(
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ),
        ));
```

i try this in Yii 2 :

```
     $DataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
                'query' => ModelName::find(),
              'criteria' => [
                'condition' => 'user_id=' . Yii::$app->user->identity->id,
                'order' => 'submitted_dt DESC',
                 ], 
            'pagination' => [
                'pageSize' => 20,
            ],
        ]);

        // get posts in the current page
        $Model= $DataProvider->getModels();
```

Error i get is unknown property: `yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::criteria` .So what is the way to set this condition and order ? 
All suggestions are welcomed

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Yii2`'s right way would be:

```
$DataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => ModelName::find()->
            where(['user_id'=>Yii::$app->user->identity->id])->
            orderBy('submitted_dt DESC'),
        'pagination' => [
            'pageSize' => 20,
        ],
    ]);

    // get posts in the current page
    $Model= $DataProvider->getModels();
```

So, you don't need `criteria` in `Yii2` as this is not exist anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can you please give me example to view this data provider as TbGridView in Yii 2 ?

Comment: @XXLend You're welcome dear, Here is an example http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/

Comment: For multiplr where conditions:          `'query' => ModelName::find()->where(['CollaboratorId'=>$collabaratorId])
->andWhere("Status=1")`

Comment: Hi, can anyone tell me how can i add subquery in it? like in select (select * from) AS .....