# Set a where condition for dataprovider in specific controller method

Tags: search, model, yii2, conditional-statements, dataprovider

I am looking to set a condition only for a single action in the controller, so I don't want to change my `search` model.

My code looks like this:

```
public function actionRoles()
    {
        $searchModel = new EmployeeSearch();
        //$searchModel->query()->where('role <> regular');
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('view_role', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
```

The commmented row shows my condition (`$searchModel->query()->where('role <> regular');`), it's pretty straightforward but I have not found a solution that works online.

For reference I tried those:

- [Yii2 how does search() in SearchModel work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779085/yii2-how-does-search-in-searchmodel-work)
- [Yii2 Modify find() Method in Model search()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718889/yii2-modify-find-method-in-model-search)
- https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/5668
- [criteria Active data provider in Yii 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27746984/criteria-active-data-provider-in-yii-2)

Answer (score 15):

Ok, I got it done, it works this way for me:

```
public function actionRoles()
{
    $searchModel = new EmployeeSearch();

    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
    $dataProvider->sort = ['defaultOrder' => ['role'=>SORT_ASC, 'fullname'=>SORT_ASC]];
    $dataProvider->query->where('employee.role <> \'regular\'');

    return $this->render('view_role', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Certainly a bit complicated and doing it in the model would probably be better, but I only want it to use it in this action and have a bunch of other actions with the same `search`model but different conditions.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it this way in the Controller

```
$searchModel = new ModelSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->query->andWhere(['lang'=>'ENG']);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try this way

```
$searchModel = new EmployeeSearch();
$searchModel->role = 'regular';
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

In Search model :

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['<>', 'role', $this->role]);
```

---

Second way pass second parameter like :

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams, $role = 'regular');
```

In search model

```
if($role == 'regular') {
    $query->andWhere(['<>', 'role', $this->role]);
}
```

Another way pass other parameter like but problem in filter time:

```
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams+['EmployeeSearch' => ['<>', 'role' =>'regular']]);
```

Comment: I only so far (have to go for lunch, will try afterwards the rest) tested your last one, that returns every entry with `role` `regular`. Will report back on the rest.

Comment: I don't want to modify the model because I am using it at many places and this is just one view, so any changes to the model are annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
**SearchModel:**

```
$searchModel = new EmployeeSearch();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);


    $query->andFilterWhere(['<>', 'role'=>'regular']);
return $this->render('view_role', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

Please also visit this link:http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-providers.html

Comment: This returns: `PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Undefined variable: query`

Comment: also include 'query'=>$query in return section

Comment: It doesn't work because $query is not a defined model.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
$searchModel = new ModelnameSearch
           (
              [ 'Attribute' => 1,
               'SecondAttribte' => '1',
              ]
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this using multi-params -

```
$searchModel = new YourSearchModel();
$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
$dataProvider->query->where('field1 = :field1 AND field2 = :field2', [':field1' => 1, ':field2' => 'A']);
```